# Is it possible to define variables in a message and use them later as variable in a function?

Tags: python, discord.py

What I want to do, is that the user sends a message like

> .create_voice name=Hello bitrate=64

that the function then takes the "variables" (I know they are still as string) and uses them in the function

(If you got any questions regarding this feel free to comment)

Comment: You cant try using differents splits? F.e. `string.split("=")` and  `string.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just store the string in a variable and then perform any operation to obtain what you need. Here is an example using split. You could also use regex for more complex patterns etc. :

```
command = "1,2,3,4"
values = command.split(",")
>>values = ["1","2","3","4"]

def test(a):
    print(a)

for i in values:
    test(i)
```

Comment: So, I used the first 2 lines of your code and built them into my code so it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At least you can skip the step spliting with " ".

```
@client.command()
async def create_voice(ctx: commands.Context, *args):
    input_args = dict() # create a dict with arguments
    for arg in args:
       input_args[arg.split('=')[0]]=arg.split('=')[1]
    guild: discord.Guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_voice_channel(**input_args)
```

But be aware, that this may produce some unknown argument errors, because the user can enter very much keywords

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string like this `name=whatever bitrate=64` to a dict you can do a bit of dict comprehension

```py
>>> raw_kwargs = "name=Hello bitrate=64"
>>> kwargs = {k: v for (k, v) in [elem.split('=') for elem in raw_kwargs.split()]}
>>> print(kwargs)
{'name': 'Hello', 'bitrate': '64'}
```

Note that the digits aren't converted to integers, we can put a simple if-else statement to cast them.

```py
>>> raw_kwargs = "name=Hello bitrate=64"
>>> kwargs = {k: (int(v) if v.isdigit() else v) for (k, v) in [elem.split("=") for elem in m.split()]}
>>> print(kwargs)
{'name': 'Hello', 'bitrate': 64} # Casted to an integer
```

In your command it'd look something like this

```py
@bot.command() # or `client.command()`
async def create_voice(ctx, *, raw_kwargs):
    kwargs = {k: (int(v) if v.isdigit() else v) for (k, v) in [elem.split("=") for elem in m.split()]}
    await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(**kwargs)

# To invoke it
# .create_voice name=Whatever bitrate=64 user_limit=99
```

To explain the dict comprehension a bit, this is how it'd look with a normal for-loop

```py
>>> raw_kwargs = "name=Hello bitrate=64"
>>> kwargs = {}
>>> 
>>> for elem in raw_kwargs.split():
...     k, v = elem.split("=")
...     if v.isdigit():
...         kwargs[k] = int(v)
...     else:
...         kwargs[k] = v
... 
>>> print(kwargs)
{'name': 'Hello', 'bitrate': 64}
```